# Is it possible to create just one xml layout for all products, while the product description changes depending on the product chosen in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-menu

I'm trying to create a POS Andriod app for my first Android class. For the menu, I implemented a scrollview for our client to choose a product of theirs. When a product is clicked, it goes to another screen wherein the product details (image and description) and 'add to cart' is found. What I did was created that menu screen, and numerous activity screens along with its respective layout xml files for each product offered. My question is, is there a more efficient way to go about this? I mean, is it possible to create just one xml layout for all products, while the product description changes depending on the product chosen? I've tried searching for a guide about this, but I'm not sure if I've been searching for the correct keywords.

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify contents of the layout with methods like

```
   TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
   description.setText("My cool product");

   description.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds
     (null, R.drawable.product1, null, null);
```